# Codeigniter - Session data not saving in database via array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session, authentication

When I enter my credentials for my login program developed in Codeigniter the sessions don't seem to be saving in the ci_sessions table in the MySQL database.

Once the form is filled in, the session will be set in the controller.php (sample code below):

```
if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
    $data = array(
       'email' => $this->input->post('email'), // posting the email input field
       'is_logged_in' => 1 
    );

$this->session->set_userdata($data);  

redirect('main/members');

} else {

    $this->load->view('login');

}
```

At the moment its outputting the following when executing:

```
Array
(
   [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1440877455
   [email] => jhon@gmail.com
   [is_logged_in] => 1
)
```

The output is using the following code in view.php

```
print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
```

The array should be outputting something similar below but its not:

```
Array
(
   [session_id] => dd7e0e2266da6481ef45faaa7e3c808b
   [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
   [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
   [last_activity] => 1387619782
   [user_data] => 
   [username] => Jhon
   [email] => jhon@gmail.com
)
```

config.php:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'form_validation');

$autoload['drivers'] = array('session');

$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form', 'html', 'security');
```

I have checked the config.php to ensure everything is set correctly and referred to the manual on Codeigniters website but still no joy in solving the issue.

Any idea's as to why this is happening? OR Any possible solutions?

Comment: Output points you have `is_logged` and `is_logged_in` properties. Where is set first one?

Comment: @Tpoika - I am currently using 'is_logged_in' which is set in the array.

Comment: Have you tried debugging proposal from answer bellow?

Comment: @Tpoika - I have I get the following: 'array(2) { ["email"]=> string(24) "jhon@gmail.com" ["is_logged_in"]=> int(1) }' It seems its not saving to the database. I have checked the autoload.php, config.php and database.php and all seems to be configured correctly.

Comment: If you use database method for sessions, it is already in db than. You just print it out.

Comment: @Tpojka - I'll give that ago if I cannot get it resolved.

Comment: What version of CI you are using?

Comment: @Tpojka - Version 3.0.0

Comment: Do you use any core controllers/libraries that could overwrite it? Auth system or something similar?

Comment: @Tpojka - This is my first program in CI I have not loaded any libraries directly into the controller.php file. Not that I am aware I am quite new to CI. The only libraries I have included is in the autoload.php as seen in my post.

Answer (score 3):

There's a number of problems here ...

> At the moment its outputting the following when executing:
>
> ```
> Array
> (
>   [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1440877455
>   [email] => jhon@gmail.com
>   [is_logged_in] => 1
> )
> ```
>
> ...
>
> The array should be outputting something similar below but its not:
>
> ```
> Array
> (
>   [session_id] => dd7e0e2266da6481ef45faaa7e3c808b
>   [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
>   [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
>   [last_activity] => 1387619782
>   [user_data] => 
>   [username] => Jhon
>   [email] => jhon@gmail.com
> )
> ```

No it shouldn't ... you're not setting "username" anywhere and the rest is [explained in the manual](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#accessing-session-metadata).

---

Let's inspect your configuration now ...

> `$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';`

^ This line is what tells the library what storage to use. If it is set to 'files', you cannot expect sessions to be saved to the database ...

> `$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;`

^ This setting is obsolete; it does nothing on CI 3.0.x.

> $config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;

^ Since you have set `$config['sess_driver']`, this setting is ignored - remove it.

> `$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';`

^ This is also ignored, and you shouldn't be using it with CI3. Set `$config['sess_save_path']` instead.

> `$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;`

^ You're not supposed to leave this to NULL. Both the manual and the inline comments in the stock config.php file say that setting this is REQUIRED!

> `$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;`

^ This also does nothing in CI3.

> `$autoload['drivers'] = array('session');`

^ Nothing in the documentation suggests this and it does nothing.

---

> I have checked the config.php to ensure everything is set correctly and referred to the manual on Codeigniters website but still no joy in solving the issue.

On the contrary, you didn't pay attention even to the most basic documentation, which are short descriptions in the config files ... You've obviously just copy-pasted your old settings from CodeIgniter 2.x and didn't follow the [upgrade instructions](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html#step-6-update-your-session-library-usage).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i will advice you to do

```
$data = array(
       'email' => $this->input->post('email'), // posting the email input field
       'is_logged_in' => 1 
    );
//Use Var_dump($data) directly under the code above and add a die statement to check if the array actually contain the data as specified above
$this->session->set_userdata($data); 

/*
** store the session inside a variable then var_dump it if it is really 
* in there
*/

$result = $this->session->set_userdata($data);
var_dump($result);die;
```

Note the changes and try to replicate samething just to confirm if those data are actually stored in an array and also to check if the session is available inside the $result

Comment: When I debugged the array using the code above I get the following: array(2) { ["email"]=> string(24) "jhon@gmail.com" ["is_logged_in"]=> int(1) }, at the moment it doesn't seem to be saving the session in the database.

Comment: Did you configure your session to be saved in the Database?

Comment: Yes I have see config.php in my post