# Codeigniter $this->session->set_userdata() not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

i am generating a session but when i generate it i am not getting `__ci_last_regenerate`  after calling `$this->session->set_userdata('sessionName',$sessionArray)` function. when i redirect after generate my session without __ci_last_regenerate the session data is not appearing on next page.i am using CI 3.1.4

```
$user_basic = array( 
    'user_id' => $user_id, 
    'email' => $this->input->post('email'), 
    'is_user_login' => 'true', 
    'language' => 'eng' 
); 
$this->session->set_userdata('user_basic',$user_basic); 

echo'<pre>';print_r($this->session->userdata());
```

Thank you

Comment: please add your code here or what you have tried so far.

Comment: see this SO question may be it helps [question-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290803/codeigniter-session-data-not-saving-in-database-via-array)

Answer (score 21):

If you are using **PHP >=7.0** then check your **codeignator version**.

If codeignator version is 3.0 or less than 3.0 then you need to update codeignator 
to current version (ex. codeignator current version 3.1.7)

Comment: Thank you for saving me!

Comment: To upgrade from version 3.0 to version 3.1.xx, simply download version 3.1 from https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/downloads.html and then just replace system folder keeping other folders as it is. This will upgrade and also session will start working

Answer (score 3):

Autoload your sessions in the config/autoload.php `$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');`

First make sure you have set your session save path. Some think like this example

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'cache/sessions/'; 
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

> **Folder permissions 0700**

Then try and set sessions on controller something like example

```
$sessionArray = array(
   'is_logged' => TRUE
);

$this->session->set_userdata($sessionArray);

// Remove the sessionName $this->session->set_userdata('sessionName',$sessionArray)
```

Then you should be able to access session like

```
<?php echo $this->session->userdata('is_logged');?>
```

Comment: can your solution get the `__ci_last_regenerate`  ?

Comment: Autoload your sessions in the config/autoload.php `$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');` and also try change this to true `$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;`

Comment: i need to know more about it.  i will google it. thanks sir.

Answer (score 0):

First load the session library :

```
$this->load->library('session')
```

Use it like this :

```
$this->session->set_userdata($sessionArray)
```

But it completely depends on the rest of your code. Upload the rest of your code for better olution

Comment: `$user_basic = array(
                            'user_id' => $user_id,
                            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                            'is_user_login' => 'true',
                            'language' => 'eng'
                        );


       $this->session->set_userdata('user_basic',$user_basic);  
       echo'<pre>';print_r($this->session->userdata());`                                                  so when i print userdata i should have a __ci_last_regenerate so that on next page i will have this session continue

Comment: ok. then your initialization should be `$this->session->set_userdata($user_basic)`. use only one argument for the function `set_userdata()` if that argument is an array of your session data

Comment: Nope the problem is not this you just need to think i am not getting  __ci_last_regenerate   which is very important to access session on others page. and genarly __ci_last_regenerate generates when session creates.

Comment: Then have you tried `$this->session->__ci_last_regenerate` ?. Or you can change `$config['sess_driver']` in config/config.php to `'database'`. Then get the timestamp from database

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade codeigniter version from 3.0 to 3.1.x

1. Download 3.1.x from https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/downloads.html
2. Copy system folder from this 3.1.x and paste it into your project by replacing current system folder.

This will upgrade the CI version and also session will start working

Comment: He's already using **`i am using CI 3.1.4`**